# Order of activity items in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

How can the order of the `activityItems` of an `UIActivityViewController` be set?

(I don't mean the order of the services in the activity view.)

Example:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [UIImage(named:"image")!, "text"], applicationActivities: nil)
```

When choosing the service "Copy" the text and image are copied to the pasteboard. However when pasting the content into the Messages app the text appears above the image.

How can the order be influenced?

Comment: Nop, it is not possible, is the app who receive the array the one that decides that to take and in witch order.

Comment: @MarcoAntonioUzcateguiPescoz seen like you're right.